# "requests.get" not saving useful youtube links

Tags: web-scraping

I'm trying to run `requests.get()` to save a collection of youtube playlists, but somehow it is not working.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re
import time
import bs4 as bs4
import json
import requests as rq

queries = ["machine+learning", "data+science", "kaggle"]
url = "https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query={query}&sp=CAI%253D&p={page}"

for query in queries:
    for page in range(1,21):
        urll = url.format(query=query, page=page)
        print(urll)
        response = rq.get(urll)
        
        with open("./dados_brutos/{}_{}.html".format(query,page), 'w+') as output:
            output.write(response.text)
        time.sleep(2)
```

It works well to save the pages, but when I try to load the page in the browser, the header of the page (Youtube) appears, but no info is displayed.

[image: Loaded page]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does the rest of the content get written to the html? I.e. is it a problem with 1) getting the content or 2) displaying the scraped content as HTML.

Comment: Hello! It's 1, getting the content. When I open and inspect the html, there is nothing there besides the header of the page.

Comment: Well, then I am going to assume that the search results aren't loaded with the initial request. There's probably some JavaScript magic going one that loads the actual results. I'd recommend looking into Selenium, it's really wonderful for scraping JS intensive pages. https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/